# How can I turn a company page into a showcase page?

Tags: linkedin

I see that LinkedIn now offers showcase pages so you don't need to have a company page for a product. My company page is at https://www.linkedin.com/company/carousel-apps and I created a company page for one of our products at https://www.linkedin.com/company/screensaver-ninja.

Do you know if it's possible to turn that company page into a showcase page? And if not, would deleting it free the name for me to re-created it as a showcase page? I don't want to delete it and have it forever stuck.